# PHP readfile or file_get_contents in a loop

Tags: php, file-get-contents, readfile

there may be other ways to do this but I'm looking for an fairly easy set-up because it's basically a one-time process.

I have 50 state directories with a handful of txt files in each one.

I want to step into each directory, "read" each file (and then do a mysql insert of each file)

I've tried a few variations, but each time I try to loop through and use readfile or file_get_contents it breaks after the first file and I get failed to open stream: errors on the remainder of the list.

I've searched for the pitfalls of using these functions in a loop expecting many reasons why not to, but not getting answers.

thanks
came back to add example code - I see there is an answer listed so I 'll check that out also. (none of this is mine, I simply found a function to capture the file list)

```
    function listFilesInDir($start_dir)
        {

        /*
        returns an array of files in $start_dir (not recursive)
        */

        $files = array();
        $dir = opendir($start_dir);
        while(($myfile = readdir($dir)) !== false)
                {
                if($myfile != '.' && $myfile != '..')
                    {
                        $files[] = $myfile;
                     }
                }
        closedir($dir);
        return $files;
        }


        $dir = 'path/to/files';
        $Docs = listFilesInDir($dir);

        foreach($Docs as $key => $fileName)
        {

        // HERE IS WHERE I TRIED THE file_get_contents
        $content = file_get_contents($fileName);

        //even doing an echo as a test would break it after the first file
        echo $content;

        //ultimately I would just do INSERT INTO here for mysql




        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some variation of the below is what i would use. YMMV depending on what you're doing. If you post your code we can address your specific implementation instead of just providing alternate solutions :-)

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/states');
foreach($dir as $file)
{
  if(!$file->isDot() && $file->isFile() && strpos($file->getFilename(), '.txt') !== false)
  {
     $content = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());
     if($content)
     {
        // do your insert code
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solution did the trick. No variation was necessary other than plugging in my path... and I'll add my insert code.

I guess, just for my own education purposes, I see that 
$file->getPathname());
was something I'll have to read up on.

Comment: DirectoryIterator is one of the useful SPL classes added in php5. the `getPathname` method give you the full filesystem path to the file or directory in question `getFilename` give you jsut the file/dir name and `getPath` will get you just the path to the file/dir. Also if you used this as your solution can you mark this as the answer - or are you waiting for more technical details on whay your code doesnt work?

Comment: Yes, I can mark this as the answer - fairly new to the SO system so I wasn't sure how that worked. (and sorry for the delay in my responses I wasn't receiving any email notification of activity)  If anyone wanted to add some info as to why the other method was failing I would find it useful but I wouldn't hold this open as unanswered for that.

thank you again, I'm often in need of these type of answers for various projects and I'm finding Stack Overflow very useful.

Comment: Well ive very rarely made use of `readdir` but im thinking its probably an issue one of the values in your `$files` array. I suspect if you were to dump that you would see something unexpected. Or it could be that the error actually occurs in the `readdir` call and its an issue with perms on the dir/file. Normally if i were not using spl i would use `glob('/path/to/files/*.txt')` to get an array of files. In general, unless im dealing with a huge amount of data i try to avoid the functions that require manipulation of `resource` types directly.