# content reading of multiple files in php

Tags: php, markdown, file-get-contents

I m new to PHP so please bear me
There is a dir name filename which contains diff sub-dir 
in these sub-dir there are some .md files 
I want to get the content of all of these files and show it like

Filename:""

Content: ""

I tried to use this but no luck

```
    <?php
$directory = "./dirname";
$dir = opendir($directory);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
     $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
     $items = explode('¬', $contents);
     echo '<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="4">';
     foreach ($items as $item) {
       echo "<tr><td>$item</td></tr>\n";
     }
     echo '</table>';
  }
}
closedir($dir);

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain the symptoms of 'no luck'? And does the `$file` prepended with directory separator?

Comment: Did you get any error messages? `$directory . $file;` isn't there missing a separator like `$directory.'/'.$file;` ?

Comment: It doesn't show the content of any of the files

Comment: @Tom K.
my main issue is to get the content of all these files

Comment: What I guess: With `$filename = $directory.$file;` you get e.g. a file example.txt something like `./dirnameexample.txt`; you need to concat the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR: `$filename = $directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;`

Comment: Tom - tried still not working

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @TomK.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142746/php-readfile-or-file-get-contents-in-a-loop?rq=1)

I tried this it is working but it give me 2 problem as i dont get the file just 
# then content 
secondly i want it to loop ove dir and sub dir but it is not

Comment: Is your ./dirname in the same folder as the php file? - Try to use full path or function realpath

Comment: Please use error_reporting and debug functions, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Oh, I see , you need recursive dir search like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2014533/3140754 - possibly that helps.

Comment: @TomK.
recursive dir search and also the content of text file that these dir and sub dir contains